# Laravel Project call services to other Laravel Project

Tags: php, apache, laravel, lumen

I have two laravel projects in diferent folders

```
var/www/html/lab1
var/www/html/lab2
```

When I access to one route of one project this route call to other project!

Example: I access to domain.com/public/api/lab1/user and this call to domain.com/lab2/api/user

Im using apache2, and I do not know what's happening

This appear in the log file

```
 File: /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php
Line: 1176
CLASS: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
traceAsString: #0 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1134): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/app/Http/Middleware/CorsMiddleware.php(8): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#5 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/src/Middleware/OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1354): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1135): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#16 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1073): Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/dev/public/index.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 {main}
```

Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost  *:9022>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api
         <Directory /var/www/html/api>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost  *:9019>
       ServerName servername
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api2
         <Directory /var/www/html/api2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you calling the second domain, in html? from the php code? Can you post the code that is doing the calling?

Comment: I dont call to second domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your documentRoot and the directory in your virtualhost is showing something different to what you stated at the top(var/www/html/lab1).

Changed the documentRoot and the directory to /var/www/html/api/public
and /var/www/html/api2/public

Because laravel bootstrap the entire laravel framework from the index.php in the public folder

Comment: Yes, the really folders its var/www/html/api and var/www/html/api2. Im sorry, but the problem persists